# Tensorflow For Poets - Upgrade to Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, image-recognition

I used the "Tensorflow For Poets" tutorial a few years ago to create an image classifier. It's amazing and I've been using it regularly ever since.

Today I have attempted to migrate my image classifier to a new Docker environment but it's running the new version Tensorflow 2 and so my script breaks.

Can anyone help to upgrade this famous tutorial script to Tensorflow 2?

```
directory = '/imageFolder'

# Tensorflow labels
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in tf.gfile.GFile('/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt')]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile('/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    # Count the folders
    def fcount(path, map = {}):
      count = 0
      for f in os.listdir(path):
        child = os.path.join(path, f)
        if os.path.isdir(child):
          child_count = fcount(child, map)
          count += child_count + 1 # unless include self
      map[path] = count
      return count

    map = {}
    totalDirectories = fcount(directory, map)

    # Walk the directory
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):

        splicedDirpath = dirpath[len(directory):]

        print "Processing ", splicedDirpath
        counter = 0

        for name in filenames:
            if name.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.tiff')):

                print name

                image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(os.path.join(dirpath, name), 'rb').read()

                predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
                         {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

                # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
                top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]
                firstElt = top_k[0];

                for node_id in top_k:
                    human_string = label_lines[node_id]
                    score = predictions[0][node_id]
```

Comment: Can you share the `.pb` file? Hard to test without it.

Comment: The file is too large to share on Stack Overflow.

Comment: can you put it on Google Drive and share a "shareable link"?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a new updated version of the **TensorFlow for Poets** in this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/images/transfer_learning_with_hub.ipynb).

If you need to **migrate** your code from **TensorFlow 1.x** to **TensorFlow 2.x**.
You can use the **compat** library of TensorFlow 2.x by basically **importing tf.compat.v1** and **executing tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()**. 
 
You can also use the **upgrade script** provided by **TensorFlow** to assist in migrating your code, this will also show you **parts of the code that needs manual changes**.

The guide in using the **automatic upgrade script** is in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade).
 
A more in-depth discussion on the guide of **Migrating your code from TensorFlow 1.x to 2.x** is in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate).